A man threatens a pianist having a concert with a sniper
I was at a home party with some friends last year and I remember clearly watching a movie, where a man with sniper threatens some pianist while having a concert.
He would be speaking to him through an earphone.
The sniper would insult the piano player telling him he's nothing but a copycat. It seemed so strange, yet exciting.
Then, the sniper asks him to play an extremely difficult classic piano composition. (in which it seems no one has played well).
While he was playing the melody, the camera would turn inside the piano showing a key getting out of the piano.
The piano player plays the melody right, then the last key of the piano he would not hit it right.
That's all I can remember.
It seemed to have a strong production. I can't remember any actors. 
It also wasn't an old movie. Definitely after 2008.

Google to the rescue!
Looks like Grand Piano (which I haven't even heard of) from 2013. Starring Elijah Wood and John Cusack. Elijah played the pianist and Cusack the sniper.
Partial Summary (matching parts bolded):

Tom Selznick was an up-and-coming concert pianist until he developed
  stage fright while attempting to play an unplayable piece "La
  Cinquette" that caused him to break down during a performance. Five
  years later, he is slated to reappear in public for a comeback
  performance in Chicago, dedicated to the memory of his late mentor,
  pianist/composer Patrick Godureaux. Godureaux posthumously acquired
  massive media coverage, due to the mysterious disappearance of his
  vast fortune. Selznick's return to the stage has been due to the
  encouragement of his actress/singer wife, Emma.
Before the concert, a house usher runs over to Tom and hands him a
  folder of sheet music, which Tom greatly appreciates, as he almost
  walks onstage without it. He opens the folder, and to his disgust,
  finds the manuscript to "La Cinquette". He crumples the music and
  throws it on the floor, and walks onstage. The concert begins with a
  three-movement piano concerto, and Tom plays brilliantly, but late in
  the first movement, he turns over his music sheet and sees a warning
  that says “Play one wrong note and you die.” Disbelieving and annoyed,
  he shrugs it off as a prank from one of the orchestra members. But
  then he turns to the next page, where another message states "Do you
  think I'm kidding? Look to your right...". Looking to his right, he
  sees a laser dot from a sniper rifle aimed at his hand. Turning the
  page again, a third message says "Call for help and I'll shoot you
  between the eyes". Scared and confused, Tom leaves the stage and
  returns to his dressing room, shocking the audience, including Emma
  and her friends Wayne and Ashley. In his dressing room, Tom receives a
  text, which tells him to look in his backpack, where he finds an
  earpiece, so he can now hear and speak with his predator, Clem. The
  voice tells him that he is in control of the situation, and if Tom
  makes any attempts to call for help, or leave the hall, both he and
  Emma will be shot. Tom then walks back to the wings of the stage,
  where Clem demonstrates the power and accuracy of his high-tech
  silenced sniper rifle from his balcony box, as he shoots the carpet
  next to the piano, with no one in the audience or the orchestra
  noticing. He commands Tom to return to the stage to begin the second
  movement.
...
Clem then tells Tom to look above him to the rafters, and to his
  horror, he sees the dead body of Wayne hanging over a light fixture
  ramp, and the shooter cautions him not to lose his focus or he will
  die. Clem then commands Tom that instead of performing Beethoven's
  "Tempest Sonata," as the conductor originally announced, he must
  perform the piece that made him infamous five years earlier, La
  Cinquette. Clem taunts Tom about the last 4 bars of the piece, which,
  five years ago, caused him to freeze up onstage and break down, unable
  to complete the performance Clem then reveals that he is a
  professional locksmith, and that shortly before Patrick Godureaux's
  death, he was hired by Godureaux himself to design a highly complex
  lock inside the Bösendorfer piano Tom is currently playing. When the
  last 4 bars of La Cinquette are played flawlessly, the lock system is
  triggered, and will reveal a key to a safe which contains Godureaux's
  fortune. He threatens Tom that the last 4 bars are crucial, and that
  Tom's life depends on it.
During intermission, Tom runs backstage to try to find the crumpled
  manuscript, only to find the janitor burning it in the basement with
  the other trash. Tom feverishly listens to the piece in his dressing
  room and takes notes on a program to help him remember. Norman, the
  conductor, then announces Tom's solo performance of the Beethoven
  sonata, but Tom interrupts him, and nervously but firmly announces he
  will perform La Cinquette, much to the delight of the audience. Clem
  warns Tom to pace himself, so as not to wear himself out. Tom plays
  the piece completely free of error, until he gets to the very last
  note of the piece: a solo D note towards the very low end of the
  keyboard, but he deliberately plays the wrong note to end the piece,
  infuriating Clem. Tom retorts back that the audience doesn't know the
  difference, and receives a huge standing ovation, having finally
  conquered the piece. Clem shouts and swears at him, but Tom ignores
  him, and introduces Emma, and much to hers and the audience's
  surprise, announces she will sing a song as an encore, with Norman
  accompanying. She reluctantly obliges, and bedazzles the audience,
  giving Tom time to find Clem.

Trailer:




No doubt, it's Grand Piano.

You're amazing! Thx
